# How to insert text in a certain cell in excel based on conditions?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am making an excel sheet in which I have a column which consists of percentages ranging from 60% - 90%.

What I want to do is, that in each of the corresponding row of each cell in the column, I need to rate it.

```
       A1     B1
A2     92%    
A3     69%    
A4     80%
```

So in the above table, e.g. A2 is 92% - therefore in the corresponding cell it should be Proficient, whereas A3 is 69% therefore it should be Mediocre, and lastly A4 which is 80% therefore it should be average. 
Hence it should produce something like the following:

```
       A1     B1
A2     92%   Proficient 
A3     69%   Mediocre 
A4     80%   Average
```

I am using Microsoft Excel, and any help would be appreciated. Can this be done in Google Sheets as well?

Once again thanks guys, and any help would be appreciated.

Regards, 
MK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP with a match criterion of 1 instead of 0 is the classic way of solving stuff like this (you can use Excel's other lookup functions and configure them to taste, but I'll use VLOOKUP here for example's sake).

Create a lookup table of your thresholds. Then, supposing your lookup table is in D:E, use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$E$10, 2, 1)
```

The match criterion of 1 searches first for an exact match. If it is unable to find an exact match, then it matches on the nearest value *less than* the lookup value.

[image]

You can obviously fiddle with your categories as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for this; it works perfectly fine, but the percentages which I have percentages in decimals as well, e.g. 45.65% or 45.50% etc. Any ideas on how can I do that, using the same logic?

Comment: @user1581917 The way above should work (I'm assuming your 45.5% -> .455 etc.) If it's not working as you want it to, can you take a screenshot and post it here? We can try to debug what's going wrong if something isn't working as intended.

Comment: I was making a mistake at my end, it works perfectly - Thank you so much!